# Grouping taskbar icons

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

A new solution I have created recently has many windows open at once, all with the same icon. However, on windows 7, 8 &10, the icons group up. I was wondering if there was a way to make this a single icon, that when clicked brings up all of the forms in the program, and minimises all forms at once.

EDIT: I have tried the 'Show in Taskbar' property but that's not quite what I'm looking for. That doesn't bind all of the forms to the single icon, it just hides the icon for the given form.

Comment: Disable "Show on Taskbar" property for most of windows.

Comment: I tried that, and that's not quite what I'm looking for. That doesn't bind all of the forms to the single icon, it just hides the icon for the given form.

Comment: What is the purpose of all forms/windows? It looks like non-standard Windows GUI. Maybe toolboxes?

Comment: Different areas that add to different tables in the databases. information such as contacts, activities Etc. From research im beginning to think you are right, and that windows simply doesn't work that way.